# How to remove a stripped bottle cage mount?

Tags: frames, repair

I was taking off my bottle cage on my Specialized Secteur sport triple, and I found the mount was spinning with the bolt. (I believe it is called a rivnut but I am not 100 percent certain.)

Before I realised, the threads were stripped. I think I am clear on how to get it, but any tips would be good; the problem is there is a bottle cage in the way.

Does anyone know how much it would cost to replace or tighten the rivnut and "rethread" the threads at a bike shop? I am not interested in a clamp-style bottle cage.

I am fairly skilled in bike maintenance but don't want to scuff the frame and don't have the tools required.

Answer (score 2):

If the threads in the rivnut are okay, you may be able to re-compress it using a matching threadded bolt and some matching nuts.   Or you can buy/borrow the proper compression tool.

A temporary repair might work to force some JBWeld down the sides, and have it essentially "glue" the rivnut in place.  This may last for ages or fail on the first ride.

If your rivnut is stripped, you'll need to remove it and replace with a fresh one. The problem here is that there may be enough damage to the frame that getting the old one out is hard, and a lack of "meat" for the new one to attach to.

The solution then is to silver-solder in a new threadded insert (not a rivnut)  This will doubtless marr the paintwork to some extent.

As for costs, we can't tell you.  Instead, ring up your LBS and ask directly about a bottle cage boss repair.

Lastly - do use antiseize compound or grease on your bolt threads in the future.  This is where it shines.

Comment: "Lastly - do use antiseize compound or grease on your bolt threads in the future." I prefer threadlocker because it prevents the screws from coming loose even if you use a very low torque. It also prevents corrosion.

Comment: @Michael threadlock is kinda opposite - its chemically gluing the parts together, whereas the grease/assembly lube is to assist undoing it later.

Comment: The nice thing about threadlocker is that it can be overcome with a certain defined force. “Worst case” you can even use heat. I never had problems loosening screws with blue Loctite and since I’ve used it my plastic bottle cages don’t come loose by themselves even with less than ≤2Nm torque and when using 1l bottles.

Comment: @Michael fair points, but OP's bolts were corroded into the bosses and removing them either stripped the thread or tore the bosses from the frame.  Threadlocker would make that more likely, whereas grease/assembly lube stops the threads from seizing.